# Text on chat buttons is gone

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

The text from my chat buttons is gone. What happened? Can I fix it somehow? Refreshing doesn't seem to help.

[image: chat screen]
[image: upload dialog]

[Chatlog for displayed messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18992480#18992480)

Running Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m on Windows 8.1. Running `ver` gives me `Windows 6.3.9600`.

---

I recall chatting in chat (sending messages), when at some point the text just disappeared. After that, opening the chat in a new tab and refreshing both didn't fix my issue.

I also went to inspect element and saw 3 errors. #1 I forgot, #2 something something master.js, #3 the chatroom url. I don't recall the error message.

When I inspect element now, I get this result:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict) https://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/8595/messages/new
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor
```

These error messages look similar to the ones I saw when the text was gone from the buttons. I'm not sure, but maybe the issue is related to `master.js`?

Looking through the resources, there's a `master-chat.js`. If this JavaScript is responsible for filling in the buttons, the it's possible that some error in the script or the parsing engine caused the issue.

Comment: Windows  6.3.9600 doesn't mean anything to 99.999% of the people. Please use the common name, e.g. Windows 7 or Windows 8.

Comment: @ShadowWizard fixed. I'm just adding info since it got upvoted and maybe someone has the same problem, but I'm not getting the problem anymore. I'm still wondering whether it was a fluke of some sort.

Comment: Cheers, my Chrome also misbehaved when in 39.0.2171.71 (for me, all the chat stars were gone) then day later it was all good again, but I didn't figure it's due to being updated to a new build. So most likely 39.0.2171.71 simply had some serious bugs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Chrome `39.0.2171.95 m` fixed the issue. I'm still not sure whether the issue was on my side, though.